# ¿Se puede solucionar este problema de desfase de fechas con el datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Estoy realizando una aplicación, en la que necesito seleccionar por fechas. Además, está en dos idiomas diferentes. El selector de fecha me funciona correctamente en euskera, aun cuando recargue la página o vuelva hacia atrás. El problema lo tengo con el datepicker en su versión en castellano, ya que en una primera selección, funciona bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al seleccionar fecha y pasar a la página siguiente, y luego regresar (para cambiar algún parámetro o insertar alguno nuevo), ocurre que retrocede más de 1000 años:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este fallo sólo ocurre con su versión en castellano. El código del datepicker es el siguiente:

```
$('#datePickerFecha').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true,
weekStart: 1,
format: selectedLanguageDateType,
language: selectedLanguage 

}).on('changeDate', function (e) {

    var fecha = moment(e.date, selectedLanguageMomentDateType);
    var ahora = moment('00:00', 'HH:mm');
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha").val(fecha)

    var fecha = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha");
    if (fecha.val() != "") {
        //fecha.val(moment(fecha.val(), WSMomentDateType).format(momentDateTypes[selectedLanguage]))
        fecha.val(moment(fecha.val(), momentDateTypes[selectedLanguage]).format(momentDateTypes[selectedLanguage]))

    };



    if (fecha < ahora) {
        //solo se comprueba en el caso de fechas hacia atras.
        //se permite cualquier fecha hacia delante
        permitido = parseInt(diasvacunacion) + 1;
        dias = moment(ahora).diff(fecha, 'days');

        if (dias < permitido) {
            valido = true;
        }
        else {
            //mostrar mensaje de error
            message = "<li><label class='validationerror'>" + literalesPage[50334] + "</label></li>";
            $("#messageBox").html(message);
            $("#messageBox").show();
            return false;
        };
    };
```

});

Y el código dentro del common.js, relacionado con el datepicker:

```
/**
Función llamada desde el aspx para que pinte el idoma seleccionado
y cree los eventos click en los idomas.
**/
function InitializeCommon() {
    $(document).on("allLoaded", function () {
        SetLanguageTextStyle(selectedLanguage);
        $(document).delegate("#languageEU", "click", function () {
            ChangeLanguage("eu");
        });
        $(document).delegate("#languageES", "click", function () {
            ChangeLanguage("es");
        });

    

/**


Función que se llama al cambiar de idioma.
    Cambia el estilo tanto del seleccionado como el del que quitamos.
    Fuerza la recarga de la página para que se cargue con los literales
    en el idioma seleccionado.
    **/
        function ChangeLanguage(selectedLanguage) {
            data = { "languageCode": selectedLanguage };
            $.ajax({
                url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname + "/SetCambioIdioma",
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (response) {
                    // Establecemos los estilos
                    SetLanguageTextStyle(selectedLanguage);
                    // Recargo la página
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    errorManagement(response, null);
                }
            });
        }

    /**
    Función que pone con estilo activo el idioma seleccionado y
    desactivados el resto.
    **/
    function SetLanguageTextStyle(selectedLanguage) {
        // Euskera seleccionado. Activamos Euskera, desactivamos el resto.
        if (selectedLanguage == "eu") {
            //Las fechas de las tablas siempre se muestran en formato español
            selectedLanguageDataTableDateType = 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy';
            selectedLanguageDateType = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
            selectedLanguageMomentDateType = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
            datatableLanguageUrl = "./JS_CSS/datatables_language/Basque.json";
        }
        // Español seleccionado. Activamos Español, desactivamos el resto.
        if (selectedLanguage == "es") {
            selectedLanguageDataTableDateType = 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy';
            selectedLanguageDateType = 'dd-mm-yyyy'; 
            selectedLanguageMomentDateType = 'DD-MM-YYYY'; 

            datatableLanguageUrl = "./JS_CSS/datatables_language/Spanish.json";
        }
        selectedLanguageMomentDateType2 = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
    }

});
```

¿Se debe a algún problema de configuración? ¿Hay alguna propiedad que se me escapa? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Pues lo he solucionado actualizando el datepicker a la fecha actual, con el evento onclick. Os dejo el código:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha, #ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_botonfecha').on("click", function () {
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha").val("");
$('#datePickerFecha').datepicker("setDate", new Date());

});
```

Gracias por vuestro interés. Un saludo